# Rails: get a specific number of random records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, random, limit

So, my app has Photos that belong to Collections. I want to be able to show 13 photos from a specific collection on a page.

I tried this:

```
c = Collection.first
@photos = c.photos.offset(rand(c.photos.count)).limit(13)
```

This works, sort of. The problem is, if the collection doesn't have a lot more than 13 photos then it doesn't necessarily return 13 photos. I need to specifically get exactly 13 photos.

FWIW In the case of my app a Collection is only created by admins/mods, so we can enforce that no collection will have fewer than 13 photos. What I need is to be able to start making the selection of photos random once more than 13 are available.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could first select 13 random associated photo IDs, then do a database query to fetch them:

```
c = Collection.first
random_ids = c.photo_ids.sort_by { rand }.slice(0, 13)
@photos = Photo.where(:id => random_ids)
```

Comment: Your comment says "up to 13 photos", will this return EXACTLY 13 photos? I can't use it if it returns less.

Comment: Well, it can't return 13 photos if the collection has less than 13 photo_ids. Otherwise, yeah, it does.

Answer (score 6):

Just sort them randomly in sql and take the first 13. 
so do:

```
c.photos.order("RAND()").limit(13)
```

Comment: Does this work in SQlite and PostgreSQL? I am not very good with SQL but I've had problems in the past between my development and production environments due to SQL differences.

Comment: You could always try and find out. I'm pretty sure `RAND()` works in most SQL implementations.

Comment: Watch out though because it is INCREDIBLY inefficient and on larger datasets will take much longer than necessary to execute.

Comment: POSTGRES and SQLite3 use 'RANDOM()'. This is database specific.

Comment: This is apparently extremely slow.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick solution..  currently using it with over 1.5 million records and getting decent performance.  The best solution would be to cache one or more random record sets, and then refresh them with a background worker at a desired interval.

Created `random_records_helper.rb` file:

```
module RandomRecordsHelper

 def random_user_ids(n)
    user_ids = []
    user_count = User.count
    n.times{user_ids << rand(1..user_count)}
    return user_ids
 end
```

in the controller:

```
@users = User.where(id: random_user_ids(10))
```